# Polygon edges showing in JS

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, html5-canvas

I am following One Lone Coder's 3D engine [tutorial](https://youtu.be/ih20l3pJoeU) in Javascript. I am using vanilla JS with a canvas to do the drawing. My issue is with the drawing of triangles: there seems to be a slight gap between adjacent polygons, which becomes more apparent when you zoom in. I am writing this on a cellphone, so I cannot access the code at the moment. I will attach it later though. Here are some images:

[image]
[image]
[image: Dodecahedron]

I have tried:

- Rounding the coordinates, as JS is notorious for numerical precision issues
- Turning off antialiasing. I also suspectd that this could be the culprit, but even after adding `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false`, nothing changed.

Comment: LOL JS has very good numerical precision (it uses doubles (64bit) while the canvas uses floats (32bit)). You can not turn off polygon anti-aliasing :( . The 2D API is not designed to render connected triangles. The only fixes are hacks (render same color stroke around each triangle to fill gap), enlarge each triangle by half a pixel width (render it 4 more times up, down, left, right) render each surface (several triangles) as one n sided polygon.  OR to avoid the hacks, render 3D content use, WebGL or the more uptodate WebGPU